# grep pattern single and double quotes

Tags: grep, double-quotes

Is there any difference between enclosing `grep` patterns in single and double quotes?

```
grep "abc" file.txt
```

and

```
grep 'abc' file.txt
```

I'm asking since there's no way I could test all possible cases on my own, and I don't want to stumble into a case that I get wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a difference if you have special characters :

Ex :

```
grep "foo$barbase" file.txt
```

The shell will try to expand the variable `$barbase`, this is maybe not what you intended to do.

If instead you type

```
grep 'foo$barbase' file.txt
```

`$bar` is taken literally.

Finally, always prefer single quotes by default, it's stronger.

Comment: Finally, always prefer simple quotes by default, it's stronger. -> You mean single quotes, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

- In double quote, the following characters has special meanings:  ‘$’,
  ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.

  The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double
  quotes ($ for variables and` for executing).

  The special parameters ‘*’ and ‘@’ retain their special meaning in
  double quotes as inputs when proceeded by $.

  ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline can be escaped by preceding them with
  a backslash.

  The backslash retains its special meaning when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’,
  ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline. Backslashes preceding characters without a
  special meaning are left unmodified.

  Also it will be helpful to check shell expansions:
  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions
- Single quote ignore shell expansions.