# What's the differences between grep '\$' and grep "\$"?

Tags: shell, grep, double-quotes, single-quotes

What's the differences between grep '\$' and grep "\$"?

Could someone give a proper explanation for the below command.

```
/usr/download/test/myshell$ cat a_file
boot
book
booze
machine
boots
bungie
bark
aardvark
broken$tuff
robots
```

Output: grep '\$' a_file

```
/usr/download/test/myshell$ grep '\$' a_file 
broken$tuff
```

Output: grep "\$" a_file

```
/usr/download/test/myshell$ grep "\$" a_file 
boot
book
booze
machine
boots
bungie
bark
aardvark
broken$tuff
robots
```

Output: grep \$ a_file

```
/usr/download/test/myshell$ grep \$ a_file 
boot
book
booze
machine
boots
bungie
bark
aardvark
broken$tuff
robots
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep pattern single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282860/grep-pattern-single-and-double-quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is an escape character for both `bash` and `grep`.

- In `grep \$ a_file`, `bash` thinks you are escaping `$`, but it doesn't need escaping, so the regexp being executed is `$`, which looks for any line that has an end (unsurprisingly, all of them do).
- In `grep "\$" a_file`, `bash` interprets double quotes, which allow a variety of bashy things to go on inside. Specifically, it still allows `bash` escapes, just like above; the command being executed is again `$`.
- In `grep '\$' a_file`, `bash` interprets single quotes, which basically tell `bash` to keep things inside intact as much as possible. Notably, `bash` will not remove the backslash. The regexp will be `\$`, where `\` removes the special meaning of "end of line" from the dollar, and a literal dollar character is being searched for.

See `man bash` under `QUOTING` for more details.

Comment: `$` is end of line, `^` is beginning.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, it is the Special meaning of Positional Parameters. They can also be used for their literal value. Ths.

Comment: @Amadan Ths for your reply.